# How can I use tsc to generate amd modules from typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd

I am attempting to use the command-line program `tsc` to compile my `.ts` file into an amd module.

Here's the example file `test.ts`:

```
module Test {
  var x = 1;
}
```

This is the command I use to generate the output:
`tsc --module amd test.ts --out test.js`

Here is my generated `test.js`

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    var x = 1;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

I was expecting to see a first line that referenced `require` and `define`, something like:
`define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {`

Any clue as to why this output is not as it seems like it should be? If I remove the `module amd` from the command I get the exact same output for my `test.js` file.

This is my version of tsc:

```
$ tsc --version
Version 0.9.1.1
```

Comment: A video I made about internal and external modules : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: btw afaik above given example is cjs not amd.

Answer (score 2):

Check the TypeScript language spec (quite readable, btw) on the difference between *external* and *internal* modules.

```
$ cat module.ts
export var x = 1;

$ tsc --module amd module.ts

$ cat module.js
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    exports.x = 1;
});
```